# Unable to go to history back at the very first load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a button to go back page from where I came from. Now after loading the page i will go through few navigation and there I will meet this back button, for this i am using the following

```
(window.history.go(-1) 
//window.history.back())
```

in the script. This not work for the very first time only after refresh it will work perfectly. Help please.

Comment: can you show more codes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to do `return false;` if you added that in HTML onclick. Or in the click handler function add `e.preventDefault()`. Make sure you specify e (event) as the argument for the click handler function:

```
function clickhandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
};
```